# how i can get photos in picasa album by FeedUri

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, picasa

i want to  get photos in picasa album by FeedUri 
i get feeduri and Separate the album id and write this code

```
public ActionResult Detail(string feeuri)
    {

        int n=feeuri.LastIndexOf("/");
        string s=feeuri.Substring(n+1);
        PhotoQuery query = new PhotoQuery(PicasaQuery.CreatePicasaUri("username", s));
        PicasaFeed feed = service.Query(query);

       //...


        return View();
    }
```

but i get an error that the url is wrong